# Django - Getting an object from an object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the object "Book" from prommotion. Book is a `ForeignKey` in "prommotion", and I filtered all the prommotions that are active. I need to get the "Book" object from the Prommotion if its active and return it.

(And I know promotion is spelled wrong)

Views:

```py
class Book_PrommotionViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Prommotion.objects.filter(active=True)
        serializer = PrommotionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, HTTP_200_OK)
```

Prommotion Model:

```py
class Prommotion(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    precent = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=255, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Prommotion'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Prommotions'
```

Book Model:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=255)
    published = models.DateField()
    edition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isbn_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Cover.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Genre.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Language.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Format.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Publisher.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Book'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Books'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Where are you trying to get the related Book, in the view, in the serializer?

Comment: So in Promotion im filtering all the promotions that are active. So i want to get the book which those promotions are for. So all the books that are on an active promotions

Comment: But where do you want to get those books? Do you want to return them in your list method instead of the promotions?

Comment: Yes. i want all those books that are on promotions to be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way to get all Books that are related to your active promotions is to extract the book ids from the queryset and pass it to a Book filter

```
active_promotions = Prommotion.objects.filter(active=True)
Book.objects.filter(id__in=active_promotions.values('book_id'))
```

Or simply filter books with active promotions by using the [double underscore syntax to follow relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships)

```
Book.objects.filter(prommotion__active=True).distinct()
```

Comment: I cant use book as queryset because the serializer is deferent so im getting an error about the fields

Comment: Pass the queryset to a BookSerializer?